# Wordpress as CMS, Without Using It As Website Platform

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the best method, if there is one, of using Wordpress as a CMS for users to input data while not actually building the website on the Wordpress platform?

One possible solution I've found is using a PHP class called "WPGet" (http://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/wpget) which fetches directly from the database.

Comment: You mean, use WordPress as the backend, but use something totally custom for the frontend?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd do that? No point in reinventing the wheel!

Comment: Let's say we have a custom built application, but want a clean interface for the client to input information.  We wouldn't want the custom application to be burdened by initiating the entire Wordpress platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Wordpress' API calls, but depending where your "custom built application" sits, it might require including numerous files in your code (not very fun/efficient)

Answer (score 0):

I have a site that requires constant updating. It's a golf club site: results, news etc all updated via wordpress by the club, or individuals with interest (juniors, ladies, seniors each have a mini-site) - and not always by me - so i have a front end, the standard site with static .php pages, which i then feed data to, by calling on posts marked in categories from wordpress, relevent to the site's page. The coding is easy and it's a quick and simple way of using wordpress as a cms, but it does strip away most of the Wordprss functionality, eg. comments,  But I even use it for galleries with lightbox.

Like i say - it's nothing major, but sounds similar to what you're asking...?